# Visual Studio Code - Java Dependency Viewer - Referenced Libraries

Tags: java, visual-studio, jar

I am currently having problems with trying to add an external library for reference. More specifically, I am trying to add the JAR files from JavaFX to my workspace.

Every time I create a new java project, I go to the dependency viewer to find the Referenced Libraries Node to add the external JARs like the original tutorial states on the getting started page for using Java on visual studio, but for some reason it never shows up.

I have tried reinstalling multiple times, and I have tried adding it manually, but I'm not sure how referencing the JAR files manually works properly. I posted a picture of what the dependency viewer looks like when I create a new java project. If someone could give me instructions on what to do right, it would be much appreciated.

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue. In my case I can see Maven dependencies, but not the Reference Library.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I have the same problem